# Что такое скелетная реализация?

Tags: java, терминология

Скелетная реализация, это реализация абстрактного класса, который имплементирует (но не реализует) интерфейс? Все просто? Гибкость заключается в том, что мы можем имплементировать любые интерфейсы, составляя новые скелетные реализации? Добавлю из блоха: "Класс, который реализует данный интерфейс, может переадресовывать вызов метода, указанного в интерфейсе, содержащемуся внутри его экземпляру закрытого класса, расширяющего скелетную реализацию."

Все правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Скелетная реализация, это реализация абстрактного класса, который
>   имплементирует (но не реализует) интерфейс? Все просто?

Да все просто, только имплементирует и реализует это все-же одно понятие на 2х языках.

Скелетная реализация, я не встречал такого термина в литературе, насколько я смог понять, это такой перевод или объяснение понятия  "абстрактный класс" в книге, которую Вы читаете .

Суть - помощь в дальнейшей реализации этого интерфейса(ов).

Пример из `jdk`:

Интерфейс мышиного слушателя:

```
public interface MouseMotionListener extends EventListener {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e);
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e);
}
```

Его "скелетная" реализация, хоть и содержит пустые методы, но дает возможность их не определять в наследниках, таким образом, те, кому нужен только один метод, его и определят, а второй получат из скелетной реализации

```
public abstract class MouseMotionAdapter implements MouseMotionListener {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

PS: то что методы тут пустые - это не требование, такая уж тут реализация...

Как-то так

Comment: Все же есть разница между  implements и реализовывать. implements - абстрактный класс не обязан реализовывать методы интерфейса. реализация - описание тела метода интерфейса. 

А сейчас вот вырезка из книги блоха:
"Во-первых, вы должны изучить интерфейс и решить, какие из методов Являются примитивами (primitive) в терминах, в которых можно было бы реализовать остальные методы интерфейса. Эти примитивы и будут абстрактными методами в вашей скелетной реализации. После этого вы должны предоставить конкретную реализацию всех остальных методов данного интерфейса." Продолжение в след комменте

Comment: "В качестве примера приведем скелетную реализацию интерфейса Мар. Entry. В том виде, как это показано здесь, Класс не включен в
библиотеки для платформы Java, хотя, вероятно, это следовало бы сделать.
//здесь приведен код класса AbstractMapEntry, не могу вставить 
Поскольку скелетная реализация предназначена для наследования, вы должны выполнять все указания по разработке и документированию, представленные в статье 15."

Comment: Вот еще вырезка. Это не ошибка перевода:
"Хотя в интерфейсе нельзя хранить реализацию методов, определение типов с помощью интерфейсов не мешает оказывать программистам помощь в реализации класса. Вы можете объединить преимущества интерфейсов и абстрактных классов, сопроводив каждый предоставляемый вами нетривиальный интерфейс. абстрактным классом с наброском (скелетом) реализации (skeletal implementation class). Интерфейс по-прежнему будет определять тип, а вся работа по его воплощению ляжет на скелетную реализацию. По соглашению, скелетные реализации носят названия вида AbstractInterface"

Comment: @Miron абстрактный класс не до конца, но все же реализует свой интерфейс

Comment: Но я же могу и не делать это вовсе. Или вы подводите к самой идее скелетной реализации? Я просто говорю, что это несколько разные термины технически. Но мне сейчас интересна только скелетная реализация

Comment: @Miron ну если брать в расчет то, что экземпляр абстрактного класса создать нельзя то он его "реализует, но не до конца" эта разница выражается в синтаксисе в виде директивы abstract, но это мутная тема, например ка понять какой интерфейс реализован до конца а какой нет в случает когда объект реализует 2 интерфейса?

Comment: Я полностью пересмотрел ситуацию и вот ее изложение:

Мы можем объединить преимущества абстрактных классов и интерфейсов, сопроводив каждый представляемый вами нетривиальный интерфейс абстрактным классом с наброском(скелетом, то есть реализованными методами) реализации(skeletal implementation class). Интерфейс по-прежнему будет определять тип, а вся работа по его воплощению ляжет на скелетную реализацию.

Comment: Скелетная реализация должна имплементировать только один интерфейс, который специально сделан для скелетной реализации(то есть предполагается, что некоторые методы должны реализовываться одинаково, а некоторые по-разному).
По соглашению, скелетные реализации носят названия вида AbstractInterface, где Interface — это имя реализуемого ими интерфейса. Примеры — AbstractCollection, AbstractList, AbstractMap,AbstractSet;

Comment: Учитывая факт того, что интерфейсы имеют кл. слово default получается, что модель блоха нужна для тех случаев, когда нужны изменяемые(не final, как в интерфейсах) переменные, которые взаимодействуют в реализованных в абстрактном классе методах?